# two definitions of initial segment

Tags: set-theory, well-orders

In a well ordered set $X$, a subset $S$ is an initial segment if

1. $S = \{x\in X: x\leq a\}$ for some $a\in X$ or $S = X$
2. Give $x\in X$, and $s\in S$, if $x\leq s$ then $x\in S$

I can see why $1$ implies $2$, but how can I proof $2$ implies $1$? How do I show the existence of $a\in X$, I think in some sense, $a$ is a "maximal element", but well-ordered sets only give the existence of the smallest element.

A side question, we know the set $X-S$ has a smallest element $y\in X-S$, but we don't have $S= \{x\in X : x\leq y\}$, because this would imply $y\in S$ as well since $y\leq y$, this seemed a little counter intuitive for me...

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps this is meant for a strict subset

Comment: You mean $S$ is a *proper* subset of $X$? Otherwise the second condition holds for $X$ itself. If this is the case then try "if no such $a$ exists, then..."

Comment: thank you, I edited my first definition

Comment: As stated, this is false. Consider, for example, the set $\omega + 1$ (that is, the set $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots, \omega\}$, ordered in the usual way). In this set, $\omega = \{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is an initial segment in the second sense - it's downward-closed. But it does not have a maximal element, and it is not all of $\omega + 1$. Perhaps the claim you are intended to prove uses $< a$, not $\leq a$.

Comment: @Reese Right. $S=\emptyset$ is another counterexample.

Comment: @Reese I think in the definition the set $X$ needs to be well-ordered, but the $\omega+1$ here is not totally ordered. And another quick question, I am just a beginning learner of this topic, but refer to my textbook, a well-ordered set needs to be a totally ordered set first, and a totally ordered set needs to be partially ordered first. By partially ordering, we need the relation to be reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric. Then if the relation is reflexive, what is the difference between $<$ and $\leq$ here? If I misunderstanding something, please correct me. Thank you!

Comment: @Nan You're correct that a well-ordered set must be totally ordered, but $\omega + 1$ is totally ordered if we take $n \leq \omega$ for each finite natural number $n$ - if you haven't studied ordinals yet, this will be much more understandable once you do. As for $<$ and $\leq$: by convention, $\leq$ is the relation defined on $X$, and $<$ is defined as "$\leq$ but not $=$".